# Cypher query with consecutive matches returning unwanted relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database about drugs. I need to run a query in Cypher with a somewhat complex pattern, so I have to use multiple match statements. I want to merge a couple of relationships, but end up obtaining unwanted relationships.

I reviewed some similar questions, but nobody else seemed to have this problem. I also had to use a similar query with a slightly simpler pattern that didn't suffer from this problem. My code is the following:

```
MATCH (x:Drug)-[:BLOCKS|:INHIBITS]->(z:Protein)-[:FACILITATES]->(process:Process)-[:IMPAIRS]->(effect:Effect)<-[:HAS_EFFECT]-(y:Drug)
WHERE x <> y
MATCH (x)<-[:HAS_PARTICIPANT]-(interaction:Interaction)-[:HAS_PARTICIPANT]->(y)
MATCH (interaction)-[:HAS_EFFECT]->(anotherEffect:Effect)

MERGE (x)-[r1:DECREASES]->(process)-[r2:IS_DECREASED_BY]->(x)
SET r1.checked = true, r2.checked = true
MERGE (x)-[r3:INCREASES]->(effect)-[r4:IS_INCREASED_BY]->(x)
SET r3.checked = true, r4.checked = true

FOREACH (ignoreMe in CASE WHEN 'TherapeuticEffect' IN LABELS(effect) THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
[...]
```

That is what I look forward to get (only `x` related to the remaining nodes, `effect` to the left and `process` to the right):

[image: Right graph]

What I'm actually getting (both `x` and `y` related to the other nodes):

[image: Wrong graph]

What is wrong with my query and how can I solve it?

Comment: 1. Are you sure that your data should not give you the results you see? 2. It is wasteful to always have a pair of relationships going in opposite directions; neo4j can easily traverse a single relationship in either direction.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, as I run the query several times just to make sure there wasn't any noise. Regarding the bidirectional relationships, I know they are not necessary, however original data was loaded from an ontology, and I decided to keep them in the graph as the are useful for validation purposes.

Comment: However, this previous query run as expected with no additional relationships: 
`MATCH (x:Drug)-[:BLOCKS|:INHIBITS]-(z:Protein)-[:FACILITATES]->(effect:Effect)<-[:HAS_EFFECT]-(y:Drug)
WHERE x <> y
MATCH (x)<-[:HAS_PARTICIPANT]-(interaction:Interaction)-[:HAS_PARTICIPANT]->(y)
MATCH (interaction)-[:HAS_EFFECT]->(anotherEffect:Effect)
MERGE (x)-[r1:DECREASES]->(effect)-[r2:IS_DECREASED_BY]->(x)`

Comment: Your data model and query are complex, and your pervious query is also complex but very different. So without some actual data to play with, it is not easy to say what might be "wrong". Can you provide some Cypher that generates data that that can show the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy way to import such data without importing the ontology. [https://github.com/rsandomingo/dinto-Neo4j] contains 3 scripts: `db_creation_script.cypher` creates the database (runtime: ~30 min), `inferences.cypher` fills some data gaps (runtime: ~10 s) and finally `proof-of-concept` contains 3 queries, with the third one being the one featured in this question. The remaining CSV file is the source file used in to import most data by means of `LOAD CSV`.

Comment: Assuming `Drug` nodes have a `name` property, run following query (slightly modified from your starting clauses). If it returns a result then either there is something wrong with that part of your query, or your query really should generate those extra relationships. `MATCH (x:Drug)-[:BLOCKS|:INHIBITS]->(z:Protein)-[:FACILITATES]->(process:Process)-[:IMPAIRS]->(effect:Effect)<-[:HAS_EFFECT]-(y:Drug)
WHERE x.name = 'propafenone' AND x <> y
MATCH (x)<-[:HAS_PARTICIPANT]-(interaction:Interaction)-[:HAS_PARTICIPANT]->(y)
MATCH (interaction)-[:HAS_EFFECT]->(anotherEffect:Effect) RETURN *`.

Comment: Running that query, I get no results -`(no changes, no records)` in Neo4j Desktop-

Comment: Do your `Drug` nodes actually use a `name` property to hold the name of the drug, like `propafenone`?

Comment: Yes, they do. In the domain, the property is called `preferredLabel` (I modified the query accordingly).

Comment: Have you checked to see if the browser is connecting result nodes? By default it will find all relationships between the nodes returned, which is useful for some cases, but not for what you're doing. From the browser, choose settings (lower left corner, looks like a gear), then scroll to the bottom and make sure `Connect result nodes` is unchecked. Then retry your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much looks like your query matches in both directions. Hard to tell without having the data.

What you can try is to debug the `MATCH` part first and see if it returns what you expect:

```
MATCH (x:Drug)-[:BLOCKS|:INHIBITS]->(z:Protein)-[:FACILITATES]->(process:Process)-[:IMPAIRS]->(effect:Effect)<-[:HAS_EFFECT]-(y:Drug)
WHERE x <> y
MATCH (x)<-[:HAS_PARTICIPANT]-(interaction:Interaction)-[:HAS_PARTICIPANT]->(y)
MATCH (interaction)-[:HAS_EFFECT]->(anotherEffect:Effect)
RETURN x.preferredLabel,y.preferredLabel // or others like return count(*)
``
```

Comment: Certainly, the query was matching in both directions via a chain of relationships that was difficult to spot, with no specific errors in the Cypher code. Basically, x was related to y, but the relationship also existed the other way round.